# Storing Paperclip attachment before record is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paperclip, attachment, cocoon-gem

I'm using Paperclip + Cocoon in my Rails app. If user submits a form but it fails validation, he needs to send image again. I would like to store it temporarily so that it would be preserved between form submits.

I.e.:

I have POST that has multiple IMAGES. I have form for POST that has nested forms for IMAGES. I would like to save IMAGE even before POST is validated - so on form refresh I can already show stored images.

Answer (score -1):

CarrierWave provides this functionality: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an easy/built-in way to do this with Paperclip. You would have to write a service that wraps persisting the object and deals with caching the image if validation fails.